# solving differential equation with a constant

Tags: interpolation, differential-equations

I have a simple differential equation like this:

> s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == A y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0,
>   30}]

where `A` is a constant. The mathematica gives `y` as a function of `x`. Now I want to change the `A` factor from 1 to 10. Then I want to find the solution `y` as a function of `A` (y[x, A]) and finally integrate over

```
[Integral]y[x = x0, A] \[DifferentialD]A
```

Comment: You might want to ask that question on the mathematica specific stackexchange site?

Comment: @Moslem Zarei What is your programming language?